# Showing that a multiplier operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space of complex valued functions on a set $A$.
We know that $\forall a \in A, f\to f(a)$ is a bounded linear functional on $X$.
I need to show that if $X$ is closed under multiplication by $g$, then $f\to fg$ is a bounded operator on $X$.

I tried to connect the values that $f$ gets on elements of $A$ to its norm, but all inequalities I get are on the wrong direction..

I know that $\forall a$ the supremum over $|f(a)|/||f||$ is finite let's call it $C(a)$, I want to show something like that $||f||=$sup over a of $|f(a)|/C(a)$, or at least some inequality in that direction..

Thanks

Comment: That won't work, the norm need not be of that form. The idea is to use the closed graph theorem, and a relation between norm-convergence and pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thanks,
Can you explain a bit more about this realtion? Im not sure how to inffer norm convergence from pointwise convergence

Comment: Try it the other way round. Pointwise convergence need not imply norm convergence.

Comment: The other direction I showed, because |f(a)|<=C(a)*||f||
But I don't think it helps me, In order to use the CGT I need to show that fng converges in norm if fn-->f in norm, I know just that it converges pointwise

Comment: To apply the CGT, you need to show that if $f_n \to f$ (with respect to the norm) and $f_n\cdot g \to h$ (also with respect to the norm), then $h = f\cdot g$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!